# IF-Exists not working in Oracle for a query

Tags: sql, oracle

Whats's wrong with the query as its giving me an error:

```
DECLARE
  con integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)as result
  INTO con FROM USER_TABLES where table_name ='TXN_TEMP_TABLE';

  IF( con = 1 )
  THEN
  BEGIN
  DROP TABLE TXN_TEMP_TABLE1;
  END;
  END IF;
END;
```

I'm trying to drop a table if it already exists but this query is throwing errors.

Comment: When asking a question about a query or code that is throwing an error, it is help to provide the full text of the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to execute DDL:

```
DECLARE
    con integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO con 
    FROM USER_TABLES 
    where table_name ='TXN_TEMP_TABLE';

    IF con = 1 THEN
        execute immediate 'DROP TABLE TXN_TEMP_TABLE';
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Tried this query but it is throwing the error: ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use. Is it because the txt_temp_table is scope of first query? I tried BEGIN END; for both the queries but still not working

Comment: @iSahilSharma: The cause of the error is straightforward and the action is: All the sessions using the session-specific temporary table have to truncate table and all the transactions using transaction specific temporary table have to end their transactions